# Odd Caching Behavior

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, webpack

We're currently deploying a React application that is bundled with Webpack. Our Webpack config is below.

We are experiencing some - to me - very odd caching behavior; after each deploy our users are being forced to do a hard refresh. If a hard refresh is not done, the `index.html` template is shown and the JS does not load.

This doesn't happen every time but it happens enough for it to be a problem.

Our `index.html` has the following in the head:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

The index.html is based on a template and we're using HtmlPlugin to inject the (hashed) scripts and stylesheet at compile time.

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
    <title>...</title>
    <meta name="description" content="...">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="..." />
    <link href="/portal/styles/app.d4e88655c7001362ca091666c25a9284.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="root">Loading...</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/portal/scripts/vendor.a2b9a0c858a0cf1aac42.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/portal/scripts/app.42d841eebfd48ad70010.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

As shown in the webpack.config, we hash each filename when building.

My next move is (maybe) going to be to not split the JS up into `app` and `vendor` but I'd rather not do that.

Edit: Adding HTML response headers

Edit 2: This happens primarily in Chrome on Windows but we've seen it happen in Safari and Chrome on OSX as well.

Edit 3: Added info about HTML file.

HTML Response Headers:

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
Cache-Control:max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:821
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Wed, 17 Jan 2018 17:00:09 GMT
Expires:Wed, 17 Jan 2018 17:00:08 GMT
Last-Modified:Wed, 17 Jan 2018 11:15:46 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:nginx/1.7.9
```

Webpack Config:

```
const config = {
  entry: {
    app: [
      'babel-polyfill',
      './src/portal/js/App.js'
    ],
    vendor: [
      'axios',
      'es6-promise',
      'prop-types',
      'react',
      'react-dom',
      'react-ga',
      'react-redux',
      'react-router',
      'redux',
      'redux-logger',
      'redux-thunk',
      'shortid',
    ]
  }, // entry point
  output: {
    filename: 'scripts/[name].[chunkhash].js', // output filename with hash'd filename
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/portal'),
    publicPath: '/portal/'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader'},
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        use: [{loader: 'babel-loader'}],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ // extract all styles to a file instead of inlining
          use: [
            {loader: "css-loader", options: {sourceMap: (isDev || isStaging)}},
            {loader: "sass-loader", options: {sourceMap: (isDev || isStaging)}}
          ],
          fallback: "style-loader"
        })
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        loaders: [
            'file-loader?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=assets/images/[hash].[ext]',
            {
              loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
              query: {
                mozjpeg: {progressive: true},
                gifsicle: {interlaced: false},
                optipng: {optimizationLevel: 4},
                pngquant: {quality: '75-90', speed: 3}
              }
            }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.woff?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        use: ['url-loader?name=[name].[ext]&limit=100000&mimetype=application/font-woff&name=assets/fonts/[name].[ext]']
      },
      {
        test: /\.woff2?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        use: ['url-loader?name=[name].[ext]&limit=100000&mimetype=application/font-woff2&name=assets/fonts/[name].[ext]']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        use: ['file-loader?name=[name].[ext]&limit=100000&mimetype=application/octet-stream&name=assets/fonts/[name].[ext]']
      },
      {
        test: /\.otf(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]&limit=10000&mimetype=font/opentype&name=assets/fonts/[name].[ext]'
      }

    ]
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  plugins: function() {
    // plugins to be used for dev, staging and prod
    let basePlugins = [
      // new CleanPlugin(['dist']),
      new WebpackMd5Hash(),
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        'Promise': 'es6-promise'
      }),
      new ExtractTextPlugin({
        filename: "styles/[name].[contenthash].css",
        allChunks: true,
      }),
      new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        names: ['vendor'],
        minChunks: Infinity,
        filename: `scripts/[name].js`
      }),
    ];

    // only prod and staging but not dev - things like minification and copying static files
    if (isProduction || isStaging && !isDev) {
      basePlugins.push(
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
          sourceMap: true,
          mangle: true,
          compress: {
            warnings: false
          },
          output: {
            comments: false,
          }
        }),
        new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin(),
        new FileManagerPlugin({
          onStart: [
            {
              delete: [
               'dist'
              ]
            }
          ],
          onEnd: [
            {
              copy: [
                // static html
                { source: 'src/index.html', destination: 'dist/index.html' },
                { source: 'src/success.html', destination: 'dist/success.html' },
                // static css
                { source: 'src/styles', destination: 'dist/styles' },
                // hide contango build for now until we're ready
                { source: 'src/book/public', destination: 'dist/book' }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
          names: ['vendor'],
          minChunks: Infinity,
          filename: `scripts/[name].[chunkhash].js`
        })
      );
    }

    if (isProduction) {
      basePlugins.push(
        new HtmlPlugin({
          cache: true,
          template: 'src/portal/index.prod.html'
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
          'process.env.NODE_ENV': '"production"',
          API_ENV: '"production"'
        })
      );
    } else if (isStaging) {
      basePlugins.push(
        new HtmlPlugin({
          cache: true,
          template: 'src/portal/index.staging.html'
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
          'process.env.NODE_ENV': '"production"',
          API_ENV: '"staging"'
        })
      );
    } else if (isDev) {
      basePlugins.push(
        new HtmlPlugin({
          template: 'src/portal/index.staging.html'
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
          'process.env.NODE_ENV': '"staging"',
          API_ENV: '"staging"'
        })
      );
    }
    return basePlugins;
  }(),
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      path.join(__dirname, "src/portal"),
      "node_modules",
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: How are you serving the html? Maybe the response headers to not cache are not there and a proxy is caching it?

Comment: @HMR Added HTML headers to my question. Everything looks good (to me at least) there too.

Comment: When you say the JS does not load do you mean the bundles don't download or they download they just don't run? What dos your html look like? what is the name of your js bundle?

Comment: @Geraint: Added index.html info to the question

Comment: are the names of the js files (i.e. the hash) correct in the html file to what you would expect them to be (the ones outputted from webpack)

Comment: @Geraint: yup, hashes match and everything works as intended after a hard refresh. I have a feeling this is webpack related but I can't reliably reproduce.